# How to use custom email template while sending mail in magento

Tags: xml, magento, email, templates, block

I am new to using Magento, problem is that I have to create custom email template for different kinds of email formats and these email formats should be editable for user from admin site also I want to send email using these custom email template.

So, I have created:

1. New module as emailtemplate
2. Database table by name emailtemplate
3. .phtml file in template folder

It's working fine, I can see template UI by running this module.
Now I want to use this template while sending email.

I tried by using  `<block type>`, I created **observer** for the same but it's not working. please suggest me any way to solve the same.